# Too many Paste Options When Using Right Click In Excel

Tags: excel, copy-paste, paste, right-click

Every time I right click within an Excel cell, whether there is something on the clipboard or not, I always get too many "Values" under paste options. Is there any way to remove these, as it can get annoying scrolling down.

I've been searching online since last year trying to resolve this and finally thought I would ask and see if someone has resolved this before.

See screenshot, below:

[image]

Comment: Seems as if something has added those entries to the cells context menu. Maybe some add-in? Can you open the VBA editor from this Excel and type `Application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset` into the immediate window and press Enter? Then try the cells context menu again.

Comment: You my friend are a genius. Thanks for your help.